# Obtain radio values that are not checked - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a simple radio group. Now what I'm trying to work out, no success yet, is how to `alert()` the values of the radio buttons that were not checked.

HTML:

```
<div id="radiogrouping">

  <input type="radio" name='test' value="hello">  hello <br/>
  <input type="radio" name='test' value="hello again"> hello again <br/>
  <input type="radio" name='test' value="yet again hello"> yet again hello <br/>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

 $("#radiogrouping").bind("change",function(value){
    var test = $(this).children(":not(:checked)").val();


    alert(test);
 });



});
```

The JS above will `alert()` the value of the first radio button if it is not checked, but only the first.

How do I get both radio button values that are not checked to be alerted?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of unchecked values

```
$("#radiogrouping").bind("change", function (value) {
    var test = $(this).children(":not(:checked)").map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    alert(test);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X2AJJ/)

---

When you use .val() it gets the values of the first checkbox that is not checked

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Completely forgot about the `.map()` function. One quick question, how would I extend it to encompass if the radio button is `:not:checked` and also if the radio button is not `disabled`? Because some are disabled and I dont want to alert those values.